# Why does my Dojo switch listener not work? Registry is not defined error

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, aop

I have a Switch with the id "universalPushSwitch"I also have a Listener, which should fire an alert if the switch status changes:

```
dojo.require("dijit/registry");
dojo.require("dojo/ready");
dojo.require("dojox/mobile/ListItem");
dojo.require("dojo/aspect");

dojo.ready(function(){
  aspect.after(registry.byId("universalPushSwitch"), "onStateChanged", 
        function(newState){
        alert(newState);
    }
)});
```

but the alert is never fired. Has anybody an idea whats wrong?

Comment: firebug says "registry is not defined"

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using? The forward slashes in your require functions indicate version 1.7+. If that is the case, is there a particular reason you are using the deprecated `dojo/require` module instead of the new AMD loader? To fix your code as it stands, you can try and set the value of your `dojo.require("dijit/registry")` call to a `registry` variable, or just use the global `dijit.registry` (no need to require it in that case).

Comment: +1 for which version of Dojo.

Comment: I want to update from dojo 1.7 to 1.8.3. I know, that i don't use the new AMD loader. This is an old Project and i am also new to all the dojo stuff. A simple translate from dojo.require("x");dojo.require("y"); to require(["x","y"], function (x,y){...} doesn't work for me so there is still the old require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
dojo.byId("universalPushSwitch") or dijit.registry.byId("universalPushSwitch")
```

instead of

```
registry.byId("universalPushSwitch")
```

Comment: dojo.byId fixed the registry problem but now it says "aspect not defined". I opened a new question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896523/dojo-aspect-not-defined-dont-understand-why

Comment: i changed dojo.byId to dijit.registry.byId so that the widget is returned and not the DOM object

Comment: oh, i forgot the byId in my post. check out my other answer to the aspect question

Comment: If you use the legacy syntax, then everything is in the dojo, dijit or dojox global namespaces. You should use dijit.aspect.after rather than aspect.after...