# dojo aspect not defined, dont understand why

Tags: dojo, undefined, aspect

I want to update from dojo 1.7 to 1.8.3 so I have to replace the dojo.connect command.

switch:

```
< div id="universalPushSwitch" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Switch" style="float:right" class="mblSwRoundShape1"></div>
```

Now I have:

```
dojo.require("dijit/registry");
dojo.require("dojo/ready");
dojo.require("dojox/mobile/ListItem");
dojo.require("dojo/aspect");

dojo.ready(function(){
  dojo.aspect.after(dijit.registry.byId("universalPushSwitch"), "onStateChanged", 
        function(newState){
        alert(newState);
    }
)});
```

Firebug says: "aspect is not defined"

PS: I know I don't use the new AMD loader. This is an old project and I am also new to all the dojo stuff. A simple translate from `dojo.require("x");dojo.require("y");` to `require(["x","y"], function (x,y){...}` doesn't work for me so there is still the old style require.

Comment: i changed dojo.byId to dijit.registry.byId so that the widget is returned and not the DOM object. But of course that didn't change anything, just for your information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
dojo.aspect.after(...);
```

instead of

```
aspect.after(...);
```

And do not stop at the next function ! :-)

If that doesn't work at once, try loading aspect the global way (with a dot, not a slash):

```
dojo.require("dojo.aspect");
```

It also could be possible, that the old dojo is not compatible with "/" and that it only works with dots !

Source:

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/require

### Edit

Here is a working fiddle based on your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Xdv2/

The main problem with your code was that you did not parse the html. dojo parser converts some specific html to "dojo javascript objects" ! You use that kind of html a lot ! You should have done a:

```
dojox.mobile.parser.parse();
```

Everything is in the jsfiddle !

Comment: i changed it to dojo.aspect.after and also changed the require from / to . but the problem is still there. Using the dojo.ready command fixed the aspect problem but now the alert fires an "undefined" instead of "on" or "off". Really frustrating for a newbie :( Thanks for your help :)

Comment: could you update your question with the code OR BETTER: go to jsfiddle.com and try to get the essence of your code running and post the link in your original question.

Comment: i updated the code above. I also tried jsfiddle (my first time :) )but dojo doesnt work for me there ( http://jsfiddle.net/HK7at/1/ )

Comment: i edited my answer and added a jsfiddle, please check it out !

Comment: greetings from GER MA NY, but originally from romania near hungary (temeswar) !

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using dojo 1.8.3 and have been using dojo 1.7, why don't you use the AMD syntax instead of the pre-1.7 ?
You would do something like :

```
<div id="universalPushSwitch" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Switch" style="float:right" class="mblSwRoundShape1"></div>
```

And in your js :

```
require(["dijit/registry",
         "dojox/mobile/ListItem",
         "dojo/aspect",
         "dojo/parser",
         "dojo/domReady!"
         ], function(registry, ListItem, aspect, parser){

    parser.parse().then(function(instances){
        aspect.after(registry.byId("universalPushSwitch"), "onStateChanged", 
           function(newState){
               alert(newState);
           });
    });
});
```

Comment: would also advise you to switch @ user

Comment: i will do after all functional stuff works right. I already tried it like that (of course my complete code is much bigger and so are the includes) and it didn't work so i put it at the end of my todo list :) Currently i have to solve a problem with xhr, if you are interested ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904255/dojo-xhr-post-doesnt-work